# Why does Kafka Direct Stream create a new decoder for every message?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kryo

I have a Spark streaming app written in Java and using Spark 2.1. I am using `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` to read messages from Kafka. I am using kryo encoder/decoder for kafka messages. I specified this in Kafka properties-> key.deserializer, value.deserializer, key.serializer, value.deserializer
When Spark pulls the messages in a micro batch, the messages are successfully decoded using kryo decoder. However I noticed that Spark executor creates a new instance of kryo decoder for decoding each message read from kafka. I checked this by putting logs inside the decoder constructor
This seems weird to me. Shouldn't the same instance of decoder be used for each message and each batch?

Code where I am reading from kafka:

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, Class1>> consumerRecords = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
        ConsumerStrategies.<String, Class1>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

JavaPairDStream<String, Class1> converted = consumerRecords.mapToPair(consRecord -> {
    return new Tuple2<String, Class1>(consRecord.key(), consRecord.value());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If we want to see how Spark fetches data from Kafka internally, we'll need to look at `KafkaRDD.compute`, which is a method implemented for every `RDD` which tells the framework how to, well, compute that `RDD`:

```
override def compute(thePart: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[R] = {
  val part = thePart.asInstanceOf[KafkaRDDPartition]
  assert(part.fromOffset <= part.untilOffset, errBeginAfterEnd(part))
  if (part.fromOffset == part.untilOffset) {
    logInfo(s"Beginning offset ${part.fromOffset} is the same as ending offset " +
    s"skipping ${part.topic} ${part.partition}")
    Iterator.empty
  } else {
    new KafkaRDDIterator(part, context)
  }
}
```

What's important here is the `else` clause, which creates a `KafkaRDDIterator`. This internally has:

```
val keyDecoder = classTag[U].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[VerifiableProperties])
  .newInstance(kc.config.props)
  .asInstanceOf[Decoder[K]]

val valueDecoder = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[VerifiableProperties])
  .newInstance(kc.config.props)
  .asInstanceOf[Decoder[V]]
```

Which as you see, creates an instance of both the key decoder and the value decoder via reflection, for each *underlying partition*. This means that it isn't being generated **per message** but **per Kafka partition**.

Why is it implemented this way? I don't know. I'm assuming because a key and value decoder should have a neglectable performance hit compared to all the other allocations happening inside Spark.

If you've profiled your app and found this to be an allocation hot-path, you could open an issue. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Very well researched! #impressed

Comment: @Yuval: I am using Kafka 0.10.x. Spark makes use of cached kafka consumers (per executor) where the cache key is identified by consumer ID, topic ID, partition ID. It makes sense to have a decoder per kafka partition or how else Spark will decode messages in parallel. What I expect is that a new decoder must be created once per partition inside a cached consumer and thats it! I don't see this problem under a light load but only when I pump 1000's of messages per seconds. Probably I am running into a "GC" cycle. Do you have any idea as in how to enable the logging present in KafkaRDD class?

Comment: @scorpio Kafka 0.10.x doesn't require a decoder, at all. It returns the underlying `ConsumerRecord`, and you choose what to do with it. Are you creating an instance of a decoder inside a `map` perhaps?

Comment: @Yuval: Added the relevant code snippet. I am specifying key and value decoder in kafka properties. Do you see an issue?